Error using GCP CloudArmor "inIPRange" operator in Terraform
Using GCP CloudArmor and Terraform, I need to allow the request when host header is "myhost" and origin IP is "X.X.X.X/32". I have this configuration:
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "this" {
  name = "my-policy"
  
  rule {
    action   = "allow"
    priority = 1
    match {
      expr {
        expression = "request.headers['host'] == 'myhost' && inIPRange(origin.ip, 'X.X.X.X/32')"
      }
    }
  }

  // other rules
}

But I get this error:
 Error: Error creating SecurityPolicy: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid
 value for field 'resource.rules[0].match.expr': '{  "expression":
 "request.headers[\u0027host\u0027] \u003d\u003d \u0027myhost\u0027
 \u0026\u0026 inI...'. Error parsing Cloud Armor rule matcher
 expression: ERROR: Cloud Armor rule matcher expression:1:49:
 undeclared reference to 'inIPRange' (in container '')

I'm following this reference. What am I doing wrong?

Silly me. It was a typo error. It's inIpRange, not inIPRange.
